# Trouble with .csv File & Variables

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Long time lurker, first time poster. I've been having trouble since updating to macOS High Sierra when using Variables. I save the Excel file as a .csv but when I go to import it into Photoshop, it gives me an error saying it could not parse the contents due to a name discrepancy (see attached photo). The column name is "sku" but obviously Photoshop is reading something different. I don't understand why the strange characters are being added to the name when it looks fine in both TextEdit and Excel. Has anybody else had this issue?

[image: screenshot]

Any/all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the CSV file, and I'm not a Mac user, but did you export the CSV using a UTF character set?  On Windows, Excel has several save-as options, and the most compatible choice is "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)", not "CSV UTF-8 ...".  It's also possible that the line endings need to be Mac specific (no CR+LF, just CR) ... Windows also has that option; not sure what's available on Mac.  If 'sku' is the first variable in your CSV, I'm guessing it's a UTF-8 issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to **FIX** it:

- when importing data sets, make sure to change you **change ENCODING** option to match your document type
- when it is set to Automatic, it gives me those weird characters
- when I change it to match my document type (Unicode UTF-8), it works perfectly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but excel saves .csv with `;` instead of a `,`
Open your csv file in a text editor and change `;`s with `,`s.

Comment: That’s not weird. Semicolons are perfectly standard in CSV files. Such files are not RFC 4180-compliant, but CSV is not a standardised format, and there is no requirement for CSV to comply with RFC 4180 in order to be CSV.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for providing technical details. I don't really know much about CSV files and I just posted what worked for me, so feel free to edit my answer.